# Woocommerce Breadcrumbs not displaying full path

Tags: woocommerce, breadcrumbs

Working on a woocommerce cart with many categories  / sub categories / sub-sub  cat's  etc.

Bread crumbs default to only displaying the Home page, and whatever page your on... its kind of stupid.

So if I navigate to `home/catalog/cat1/subcat1/product`, the bread crumbs only display; `home/catalog/product`... What's the point of bread crumbs if you can't navigate your path backwards?

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: I think, woocommerce has the reason to do that. We can't say woocommerce programmer is a dumb person right ? If you dont like the woocommerce way, then create your own .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone else is looking, putting this in fuctions.php helped.

```
// Breadcrumbs Display Category Name // 

function get_breadcrumb_category( $cat ) {
    $post = get_post( $post->ID );
    $post_type = $post->post_type;
    $taxonomy = $cat;

    $f_categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
    $f_category = $f_categories[0];

    if ( $f_category->parent != 0 ) {
       $f_category_id    = $f_category->parent;
       $parent_array     = get_term_by('id', $f_category_id, $taxonomy, 'ARRAY_A');
       $f_category_name  = $parent_array["name"];
       $term_link        = get_term_link( $f_category_id, $taxonomy );
    } else {
        $f_category_id    = $f_category->term_id;
        $f_category_name  = $f_category->name;
        $term_link        = get_term_link( $f_category_id, $taxonomy );
    }

    if ( $f_categories && ! is_wp_error($f_categories) ) {
      return '<a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $f_category_name . '</a>';
     }  else {
      return '';
       }
    }

    function x_breadcrumbs() {

    if ( x_get_option( 'x_breadcrumb_display', '1' ) ) {

      GLOBAL $post;

      $is_ltr         = ! is_rtl();
      $stack          = x_get_stack();
      $delimiter      = x_get_breadcrumb_delimiter();
      $home_text      = x_get_breadcrumb_home_text();
      $home_link      = home_url();
      $current_before = x_get_breadcrumb_current_before();
      $current_after  = x_get_breadcrumb_current_after();
      $page_title     = get_the_title();
      $blog_title     = get_the_title( get_option( 'page_for_posts', true ) );
      $post_parent    = $post->post_parent;

      if ( X_WOOCOMMERCE_IS_ACTIVE ) {
        $shop_url   = x_get_shop_link();
        $shop_title = x_get_option( 'x_' . $stack . '_shop_title', __( 'The Shop', '__x__' ) );
        $shop_link  = '<a href="'. $shop_url .'">' . $shop_title . '</a>';
      }

      echo '<div class="x-breadcrumbs"><a href="' . $home_link . '">' . $home_text . '</a>' . $delimiter;

        if ( is_home() ) {

          echo $current_before . $blog_title . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_category() ) {

          $the_cat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ), false );
          if ( $the_cat->parent != 0 ) echo '<a href="'.get_permalink(102).'">'.get_the_title(102) .'</a>';
          echo $current_before . single_cat_title( '', false ) . $current_after;

        } elseif ( x_is_product_category() ) {

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $shop_link . $delimiter . $current_before . single_cat_title( '', false ) . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . single_cat_title( '', false ) . $current_after . $delimiter . $shop_link;
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_product_tag() ) {

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $shop_link . $delimiter . $current_before . single_tag_title( '', false ) . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . single_tag_title( '', false ) . $current_after . $delimiter . $shop_link;
          }

        } elseif ( is_search() ) {

          echo $current_before . __( 'Search Results for ', '__x__' ) . '“' . get_search_query() . '”' . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {

          if ( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) == is_front_page() ) {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            if ( $is_ltr ) {

              $f_category = get_the_category();

              if ( $f_category[0]->parent != 0 ) {
                 $f_category_id = $f_category[0]->parent;
                 $f_category_name = get_cat_name( $f_category_id );
              } else {
                 $f_category_id = $f_category[0]->term_id;
                 $f_category_name = $f_category[0]->name;
              }

              echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $f_category_id ) . '">' . $f_category_name . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
            } else {
              echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $delimiter . '<a href="' . get_permalink( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) ) . '">' . $blog_title . '</a>';
            }
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_portfolio() ) {

          echo $current_before . get_the_title() . $current_after;

        } elseif ( x_is_portfolio_item() ) {

          $link  = x_get_parent_portfolio_link();
          $title = x_get_parent_portfolio_title();

          if ( $v = get_breadcrumb_category('portfolio-category') ) {
            $portfolio_category = $delimiter . $v;
          } else {
            $portfolio_category = '';
          }

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a>' . $portfolio_category . $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $portfolio_category . $delimiter . '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a>';
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_product() ) {

         if ( $v = get_breadcrumb_category('product_cat') ) {
           $product_category = $delimiter . $v;
         } else {
           $product_category = '';
         }

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $shop_link . $product_category . $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $product_category . $delimiter . $shop_link;
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_buddypress() ) {

          if ( bp_is_group() ) {
            echo '<a href="' . bp_get_groups_directory_permalink() . '">' . x_get_option( 'x_buddypress_groups_title', __( 'Groups', '__x__' ) ) . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . x_buddypress_get_the_title() . $current_after;
          } elseif ( bp_is_user() ) {
            echo '<a href="' . bp_get_members_directory_permalink() . '">' . x_get_option( 'x_buddypress_members_title', __( 'Members', '__x__' ) ) . '</a>' . $delimiter . $current_before . x_buddypress_get_the_title() . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . x_buddypress_get_the_title() . $current_after;
          }

        } elseif ( x_is_bbpress() ) {

          remove_filter( 'bbp_no_breadcrumb', '__return_true' );

          if ( bbp_is_forum_archive() ) {
            echo $current_before . bbp_get_forum_archive_title() . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo bbp_get_breadcrumb();
          }

          add_filter( 'bbp_no_breadcrumb', '__return_true' );

        } elseif ( is_page() && ! $post_parent ) {

          echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_page() && $post_parent ) {

          $parent_id   = $post_parent;
          $breadcrumbs = array();

          if ( is_rtl() ) {
            echo $current_before . $page_title . $current_after . $delimiter;
          }

          while ( $parent_id ) {
            $page          = get_page( $parent_id );
            $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $page->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( $page->ID ) . '</a>';
            $parent_id     = $page->post_parent;
          }

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            $breadcrumbs = array_reverse( $breadcrumbs );
          }

          for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $breadcrumbs ); $i++ ) {
            echo $breadcrumbs[$i];
            if ( $i != count( $breadcrumbs ) -1 ) echo $delimiter;
          }

          if ( $is_ltr ) {
            echo $delimiter . $current_before . $page_title . $current_after;
          }

        } elseif ( is_tag() ) {

          echo $current_before . single_tag_title( '', false ) . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_author() ) {

          GLOBAL $author;
          $userdata = get_userdata( $author );
          echo $current_before . __( 'Posts by ', '__x__' ) . '“' . $userdata->display_name . $current_after . '”';

        } elseif ( is_404() ) {

          echo $current_before . __( '404 (Page Not Found)', '__x__' ) . $current_after;

        } elseif ( is_archive() ) {

          if ( x_is_shop() ) {
            echo $current_before . $shop_title . $current_after;
          } else {
            echo $current_before . __( 'Archives ', '__x__' ) . $current_after;
          }

        }

      echo '</div>';

    }
}
```